# Why does ref in C++0x not behave as expected?

Tags: c++11

I'm very sorry for my previous miswording. So I rephrased this question as follows:

**The simplest C++0x code below should be not valid:**

```
#include <functional>

template<class T_>
void f(T_ obj) 
{
    Obj++; // OK that is as expected.
    static_cast<int&>(obj) = 2; // Though ugly, this is still OK.

    obj = 2; // However, this line will generate a compiler error
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    f(std::tr1::ref(i));
}
```

Who can tell me the exact semantics of ref?

Comment: What is `ref`?  Please post a complete, compilable program.

Comment: -1 incomplete code, undefined terms, assertion of subjective belief about the undefined thing

Comment: I like this one.  Maybe it'll be the start of a new trend.  Post example of construct doing what it's supposed to do and then bitch about it's inability to do anything.

Comment: Who the heck closed the question after it was actually fixed?

Comment: Example: `struct X { int &x; }; int z = 10; X a = { z }; X b = { z }; b = a;` doesn't work, but `struct X { tr1::reference_wrapper<int> x; }; int z = 10; X a = { tr1::ref(z) }; X b = { tr1::ref(z) }; b = a;` does.

Comment: It was fixed?  Still looks broken to me.  It's not even a question.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You pointed out the root cause, but not give a solution. In my opinion, ref(obj) should behave exactly like r where T& r = obj. Almost all of the existing overloaded operators do such a thing.

Comment: @xmllmx Not really, reference_wrapper behaves differently. Try `obj.get() = 2`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: If using obj.get() = 2; then the type T must always be reference_wrapper<...>, that will pose many restrictions on the template function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is that there is no suitable assignment operator to apply. The only candidate is this:

```
reference_wrapper& operator=(const reference_wrapper<T>& x);
```

A `reference_wrapper` acts as a reference with the help of implicit conversion operators:

```
operator T& () const;
```

However, an implicit conversion will not happen on the left side of the assignment operator.

If you are expecting this template to support `reference_wrapper`, perhaps you can work around in ways like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
T& get(T& value)
{
    return value;
}

template <class T>
T& get(std::reference_wrapper<T>& w)
{
    return w.get();
}


template<class T_>
void f(T_ obj)
{
    //obj = 2;
    get(obj) = 2;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    f(std::ref(i));
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    f(3.14); //at the same time, we want this also to work
}
```

As to why `reference_wrapper` doesn't have an assignment operator for stored type, not sure. Boost's version doesn't have either, and they simply say that this class "usually allows the function templates to work on references unmodified". Guess this is just not one of those cases.

Comment: Your solution works. But that looks not like the most uniform way to treat a real reference and a reference_wrapper. In my opinion, get(obj) = 2; is far from elegant than obj = 2;

Comment: @UncleBens: "As to why reference_wrapper doesn't have an assignment operator for stored type, not sure. Boost's version doesn't have either, and they simply say that this class "usually allows the function templates to work on references unmodified". Guess this is just not one of those cases."

Comment: @UncleBens: Your explanation is convincing. I think this is by design to prevent modify the referenced object implictly.

Comment: Otherwise, it is easy to do that by adding a membe function like T& operator =(const T& obj) { return m_realObj = obj; }.Deliberately not to provide such a member funtion can prevent programmers from misuse.

Comment: @xmllmx reference_wrapper is a wrapper for passing references, if you would allow assignment operator, it would break its semantics. What would the compiler do in this case `int x; int &y = x; reference_wrapper<int> z = y; int a = 10; int &b = a; z = b;`? Would it store 10 into x or just change the wrapper reference?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: We can make a rule to define whether it stores 10 into x or just changes the wrapper reference. It is up to the designer of ref; To me, I think it is more natural to store 10 into x.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Storing 10 might make sense. However, if the right side is also a `reference_wrapper`, it would "reseat" the reference. Probably it would be confusing if `a = b;` could have two very different results, even though `a` and `b` are supposed to represent (or be) just references to an object.