# Why is this simplest C++0x code not valid?

Tags: c++11, ref

I encountered a weird problem just now.

The source code is simple and self-evident as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

template<class T_>
void show_size(T_ coll)
{   
    cout << coll.size();
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> coll;
    coll.push_back(1);

    show_size(ref(coll));

    return 0;
}
```

The VC++ 2010 reports:

**error C2039: 'size' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::reference_wrapper<_Ty>'**

As we know, reference_wrapper can automatically convert itself to its underlying type, here is `vector<int>`. Why is such simple code not valid?

Comment: This is pretty much the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311622/why-does-ref-in-c0x-not-behave-as-expected. Again, implicit conversions don't happen on member access. My suggestion would be the same free `get` function as in the other thread: `get(coll).size();`.

Comment: @UncleBens: Many thanks for your help. I just wonder why ref()'s behavior is so counterintuitive. If my template function must explicitly use get(), then the function is less generic. To me, it is some "bad smell" in code

Comment: The language simply doesn't allow implicit conversions with the dot operator. There may be a code smell, but it might also be that you are so persistently passing things by value and then expect the parameter to be a reference.

Comment: That's not "simplest" C++0x code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't that's the whole point of the reference wrapper, because it doesn't decay from the reference, unless explicitly requested using `.get()`

Edit: don't mix up the boosts reference wrapper with the standard one, the boost one actually has implicit conversion (but the target functionality is a little bit different)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The template function show_size does not and should not know whether the type T_ is a reference_wrapper. If I use cout << coll.get().size(); then show_size() could not take an ordinarary vector object as its argument. That is not my design goal.

Comment: @xmllmx You have a template that takes value, but you are trying to force feed it a reference. That is not a good design.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The C++ pre-standard 20.8.4.3 (N3126) clearly defines operator T&() const; so implicitly conversion conforms with the C++ pre-standard.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: My design goal is: The default case is pass by value; however, if the caller think its argument is too big to pass by value, he can explicitly use ref to pass by reference. This is also one of the design rules of STL.

Comment: @xmllmx Uh? STL is using constant references. Pass by value only makes sense for POD types, anything bigger should be usually passed as constant reference. OK, you are right about the implicit conversion, but that won't kick in the this case. It would kick in if you would pass `reference_wrapper<int>` as `int&`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation> OutputIterator transform(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op); This is excerpted from N3126. Note that the function object op is pass by value. op may be a heavy object in some cases; though in most cases it is light-weight.

Comment: @xmllmx In case you didn't notice, iterators are behaviourally pointers (not to mention, that all algorithms are backward compatible with pointers). So passing them by value is the only option.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Provided that the caller fully understands show_size(...)'s semantics; I just want to give the caller an option of passing by value or reference by design.

Comment: @xmllmx Then take a constant reference.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Pass-by-const-reference is not always the best way. For example, if the caller want to pass a char object, Pass-by-reference would be slower than pass-by-value, because of adding an indirect level. So I want to let the caller decide to use which way based on different situations.

Comment: @xmllmx Pass by const reference actually allows the compiler more optimizations then pass by value, but, whatever, this discussion is endless...

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I just wonder why ref()'s behavior is so counterintuitive. If my template function must explicitly use get(), then the function is less generic. To me, it is some "bad smell" in code.